# Deserializing XML has null object

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML class structure:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Envelope
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public Body Body { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body")]
public class Body
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CustomerBundleMaintainConfirmation_sync_V1", Namespace = "http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global")]
    public CustomerMaintainConfirmation CustomerMaintainConfirmation { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "CustomerBundleMaintainConfirmation_sync_V1")]
public class CustomerMaintainConfirmation
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Log")]
    public Log Log { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Log")]
public class Log
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MaximumLogItemSeverityCode")]
    public string MaximumLogItemSeverityCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Item")]
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Item")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "TypeID")]
    public string TypeID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CategoryCode")]
    public string CategoryCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SeverityCode")]
    public string SeverityCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Note")]
    public string Note { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the XML I am working with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:Header />
   <soap-env:Body>
      <n0:CustomerBundleMaintainConfirmation_sync_V1 xmlns:n0="http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global" xmlns:prx="urn:sap.com:proxy:LBK:/1SAI/TAE6F3228CC6D723FF1823E:804">
         <Log>
            <MaximumLogItemSeverityCode>3</MaximumLogItemSeverityCode>
            <Item>
               <TypeID>018</TypeID>
               <CategoryCode>YES</CategoryCode>
               <SeverityCode>0</SeverityCode>
               <Note>TestNotes</Note>
            </Item>
         </Log>
      </n0:CustomerBundleMaintainConfirmation_sync_V1>
   </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

When I attempt to deserialize this data into my classes, for whatever reason the "Log" class is null. Envelope, Body and CustomerMaintainConfirmation are all populated correctly. I see no reason why this is the case, but I've been staring at this for so long as this point I'm absolutely sure I am missing a mistake in and amongst my code somewhere.

This last piece of code is inside of the method that does the actual deserializing:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));

using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
{
    return (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(responseReader);
}
```

I'm still working through it, but if anyone could point out any issues they might see with what I've provided, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just miss the empty namespace indication on your element:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "CustomerBundleMaintainConfirmation_sync_V1")]
public class CustomerMaintainConfirmation
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Log", Namespace = "")]
    public Log Log { get; set; }
}
```

This is required, as apparently, your `Log` element has the empty namespace even though the `CustomerBundleMaintainConfirmation_sync_V1` above has a nonempty one.

That's the only change in your code to [make it work](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GPF0Gh) as shown in a fiddle.

Comment: This is one of those bittersweet answers. I love how simple my mistake was, but hate myself for it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you have any insight on why Log requires a namespace to be deserialized properly? I have no idea.

Comment: Without an explicit namespace the `Log` node takes the namespace of its parent. You can easily verify that by creating a non empty object, serializing it and examining the output. This is a general approach to testing possible namespace issues.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

It's a namespace inconsistency. It deserializes with this change:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "CustomerBundleMaintainConfirmation_sync_V1")]
public class CustomerMaintainConfirmation
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Log", Namespace = "")]
    public Log Log { get; set; }
}
```